# How to disable <rich:inplaceInput>?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

There is some way to disable ? I want allow or not allow user to edit data. Maybe I need other component?

Answer (score 1):

Just display an outputText instead of an inplaceInput when you don't want to allow edit.  Use CSS to make it look like an inplaceInput.  But you may have user confusion if they can't edit something that looks like an editable thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this by setting the editEvent attribute of the rich:inpaceInput.
"isFieldModificationRigth" is a public method in the secBean returning a boolean value.

```
<rich:inplaceInput id="fieldId" value="#{bean.field}"
editEvent="#{secBean.fieldModificationRight? 'onclick': 'none'}"
```

I hope it will help you!